# Can't select some Facebook classes with jQuery (Chrome Extension)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, facebook, google-chrome

Long story short.

If I use a CSS content_script with the following code...

```
._o46._nd_ ._hh7 {
background-color:#333!important;}
```

...it works. ***It changes the Facebook Messenger message bubble color to #333.***

But I need to do it with JS, so I'm trying to do the following with a JS content_script:

```
$("._o46._nd_._hh7").css("background-color", "#333")
```

But, yeah, it doesn't work for some reason I'm not aware of.

JQuery is included, and it's working because I can change the body color from the Facebook page with it. It seems like it's Facebook Messenger specific.

I tried modifying the selector to all possible ways. I even tried to select only the **._hh7** class (to change all message bubbles, not only the sender's) to see if it works but it still doesn't do the job.

I have no clue what am I doing wrong or if I am doing something wrong at all. I'm new to Chrome Extensions, but the fact that I can change the body color with no problem makes me wonder WHAT

Answer (score 0):

The css selector is different than the jquery selector. Update jquery to include the space:

```
$("._o46._nd_ ._hh7").css("background-color", "#333")
```

Comment: Actually, my jQuery selector's classes were initially like that, but it doesn't work this way. That's why I started testing other ways of writing the classes in the selector and ended up with the question's one.

Comment: Okay, do you have the js file included in the content script? 

  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://www.google.com/*"],
      "css": ["mystyles.css"],
      "js": ["jquery.js", "myscript.js"]
    }
  ],

If so, you can check to make sure the file is included in the chrome devtools under Sources tab. Above the files to the left there should be an arrow dropdown with the option "Content Scripts".

Comment: It's included, I can even change the style of static elements from the Facebook site (like apply border-radius to the profile pics). I think the problem is with the dynamic ones (the messages).

Comment: Take a look at the html of the messenger. Perhaps its in an iframe or a socket and can't be manipulated.

Comment: I don't know what a socket is, but it's not iframe.